# How to implement dark mode in NativeScript V8 with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, nativescript

I'm currently writing a NativeScript Angular application. Now I want to properly implement dark mode. (There is already some kind of automatic dark mode when using `@NativeScript/Theme`, but that doesn't work properly)
The way I currently style my components is:
I have a `_variables.scss` file where I declare variables (For example: `$bg: #fff`)
and a `_app-common.scss` file where common styles for labels buttons etc. are defined
and for every component it's own scss file using `_variables.scss`

I know that I can switch Theme using `Theme.setMode()`

How can I set the variables in `_variables.scss` according to the selected Theme?

Comment: Hey welcome and thanks for asking a question! It would be helpful if you provide some actual code and/or links to what you're referring to